# Can bracers of armor have magic armor special abilities?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

Can [magic armor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/) special abilities be put on [*bracers of armor*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bracers-of-armor/)?

Answer (score 12):

**Yes (except fixed price enhancements)**

As per the Core Rulebook page 505 and Ultimate Equipment page 272 (quoted below):

> Alternatively, bracers of armor can be enchanted with armor special abilities. ... Special abilities usually count as additional bonuses for determining the market value of an item, but do not improve AC. Bracers of armor cannot have a modified bonus (armor bonus plus armor special ability bonus equivalents) higher than +8. Bracers of armor must have at least a +1 armor bonus to grant an armor special ability. Bracers of armor cannot have any armor special abilities that add a flat gp amount to their cost.

Comment: @thomas that is another question. Ask it. However, I recommend you make a trip to the PRD where those answers are provided.